# Parametrized query using LIKE with Snowflake and pass the values from Snowflake .NET Connector

Tags: c#, .net, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to use many LIKE with parameters in .Net connector to snowflake, my code:

Snowflake SQL:

```sql
 select * from Table1 where Col1 Like '%Val1%'
```

which returns data.

.Net:

```cs
 string query = $"select * from Table1 where Like '%:Val1%'";
 var param = cmd.CreateParameter();
 param.ParameterName = "Val1";
 param.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
 param.Value = Value1;
 cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
 var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

This code does not return any data.

Comment: Try something like this: string query = $"select * from Table1 where Like '%" + Val1 + "%'";

Comment: This is sql injection which needs to be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, pass %% in value

```
string query = $"select * from Table1 where Like (:Val1)";
var param = cmd.CreateParameter();
param.ParameterName = "Val1";
param.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
param.Value = "%" + Value1 + "%";
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```